# Facebook Graph Check-In Count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is a kind of 2 part question...

what i need todo is get a count of the amount of people checking into a facebook page. (users who have checked in via facebook places on their mobile)

question number 1, is it even possible to get this information? I have looked through the data returned when you do a query on the public information of a page (for example: https://graph.facebook.com/126049473493) but this doesn't seem to have the data I need....

Question 2, is how would I go about doing this? I am new to the whole FaceBook API, so need some quite detailed help in regards to this problem...

I hope someone is able to help?

Many Thanks!

Tom Kirby.